# Find a 10 digit integer in which the first n digits are divisible from 1 to n

Tags: python

Looking for a 10 digit integer with distinct digits so that the first n digits are divisible from 1 to n.

A smaller example is the 123.

1 is divisible by 1
12 is divisible by 1 and 2
123 is divisible by 1,2 and 3

I wrote some code to try and do this automatically:

```
import sympy
import itertools

x = itertools.permutations('1234567890',10)

for s in x:

    string_number = ''.join(s)

    for j in range(1, len(string_number)):

        a = set(range(1,j+1))

        divisors = set( sympy.divisors( int(string_number[:j] ) ) )

        if not (a.issubset(divisors) and a!=divisors):
            break
    print('FOUND IT %s'%string_number)
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I think it is because of the logic in the last bit.  How can I make sure that if a number violates the conditional, that I move on to the next number, and how can I make sure that if the number obeys the conditional, that I select the correct number to print?

Comment: this is a euler project challenge?

Comment: No, but it sounds like it would be a good one.  Just a brain teaser I found on reddit.

Comment: I would try to generate such a number by adding each digit at each step and use backtracking rather than generating all possible sequences and checking it

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your `break` command at the end will break from the inner `for` loop. Imperatively speaking, you could set a flag and have it be tripped before the line with `break`. If upon exiting the loop the flag hasn't been tripped, then it means that the number should be printed.

Comment: You say `123` is divisible by `1`, `2` and `3`. But `123` is *not* divisible by `2`. Do you just want the first `n` digits to be divisible by `n`, for each `n`? (Otherwise, I think there's no solution to your problem, since anything ending in an odd digit is going to have trouble being divisible by `2`, for example, and you'll end up with at least one substring that ends in an odd digit and has length at least 2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of enumerating *all* the possible permutations, you could create the numbers one digit at a time, and just continue when the number is valid so far. This is a basic depth-first-search.

You could also make it a generator function to find just the first, or *all* such numbers. Here's a rather straight-forward implementation, without any optimizations:

```
def find_number(stop, number=""):
    if len(number) == stop:
        yield number

    for d in "1234567890":
        if d not in number:
            new_num = number + d
            if int(new_num) % len(new_num) == 0:
                for n in find_number(stop, new_num):
                    yield n
```

Example:

```
>>> next(find_number(10))
3816547290
>>> list(find_number(9))
['381654729', '381654720', '783204165', '801654723', '081654327']
```

---

But *10!* possible numbers is not *all* that much, either, so your exhaustive approach should work as well, if you can wait a few seconds. How about putting it all into a horrible one-line list comprehension/generator expression?

```
next(s for s in map(''.join, itertools.permutations('1234567890', 10)) 
     if all(int(s[:i]) % i == 0 for i in range(1, len(s)+1)))
```

---

As noted in comments, the problem seems to be the `break`, which just breaks form the inner loop, but does not skip the `print` statement. I did not try this, as I don't have `sympy` installed right now, but you should be able to fix this using a `for/else` loop:

```
for j in range(1, len(string_number)):
    a = set(range(1,j+1))
    divisors = set( sympy.divisors( int(string_number[:j] ) ) )
    if not (a.issubset(divisors) and a!=divisors):
        break
else:
    print('FOUND IT %s'%string_number)
```

Comment: From the OP's description, it looks as though the condition needs to be stronger than this: you need `all(int(s[:i]) % j == 0 for i in range(1, len(s) + 1) for j in range(1, i+1))`.

Comment: Hmm, but that's not possible, since any number ending in an odd digit isn't going to be divisible by `2`. Ignore me ...

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, OP's first sentence does sound somewhat like that, but I don't think there is any number with that property, and certainly not a permutation of the digits from 0 to 9. Also, it contradicts the "123" example.